# ECommerce Order Confirmation Email Format

Tags: website-design, email

I have created a custom ECommerce application. Everything is fine. Now, I only need to send a order confirmation email detail to user and the supplier. But I am not finding any UI for this. Can someone provide me a sample UI for order confirmation email detail?

Comment: I suggest that you sign up for a few accounts with some bigger e-commerce companies, and see what their confirmation emails are like. Learn from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something generic, but should help you get started.
http://www.emaildesignreview.com/tag/confirmation-emails/